# Energy conservation and Lorentz invariants

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, collision

In relativistic collision theory,How can we deduce energy is conserved by using Lorentz transformation?

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you mean? we use energy conservation, it has nothing to do with Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.